# HTML unit basics failing

Tags: java, htmlunit

The very basic example from HTMLUnit the website is not compiling in Java:

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net");
```

I get an error on the page variable of: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Page to HtmlPage. I don't understand why this is occuring I have all the jar files and have the correct imports!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you're using an older version of HtmlUnit, that hasn't been made generic, or you're using JDK1.4 or older. The last version is the version 2.9. Check the version you're using.

Comment: I am on JDK 1.6 and I have version 2.9 of HtmlUnit

Comment: Then it should compile, because the compiler uses the type of the page variable to infer the generic type to use to call the method.

Comment: Correction, I am on 1.4... so begins the long process of convincing IT to allow me to upgrade the JDK

Comment: Well, tell them that 1.4 is not supported anymore since October 30th, 2008, Java 5 is not supported since October 8th, 2009, and Java 6 will be EOLed in November 2012. Being on 1.4 is like running Windows 95.

Comment: Just updated to 1.7 still getting this issue, any further help?